# Coded Ui get past Loading Screen on all browsers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loading, coded-ui-tests

I am using Microsoft Coded Ui on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

I am building coded Ui tests for the website am running into a problem on Chrome and Firefox. The website is [onboard.passageways.com](https://onboard.passageways.com/). There is a a div that has this information:

`<div id="loadingOverlay" data-bind="fadeVisible: loading" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999; background: rgb(204, 204, 204);">`

Chrome and Firefox render the page so fast that they see the loadingOverlay when the style is `"display: table"`. This loading overlay is on almost every part of the site.

My question is how do I tell Chrome and Firefox to wait for the loadingOverlay to display none so that it can click on the elements in the background.

I have tried this code but it keeps saying that the collection is at 1.

```
public static HtmlDiv GetOverlay(UITestControl parent, string id)
    {
        var div = new HtmlDiv(parent);
        div.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, id);

        GetOverlayProperty(div);
        return div;
    }

    private static UITestControlCollection GetOverlayProperty(HtmlDiv overlay)
    {
        overlay.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, "display: table",
            PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

        UITestControlCollection collection = overlay.FindMatchingControls();

        if (collection.Any())
        {
            GetOverlay(browser, "loadingOverlay");
        }

        return collection;
    }
```

My Test Initialize

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void ClassInitializer()
    {
        BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Browser-Type");

        CodedUIUtils.browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Browser-Url")));

        CodedUIUtils.browser.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
        CodedUIUtils.browser.Maximized = false;
    }
```

My Login Test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LoginAndLogout()
    {
        CodedUIUtils.ClickButton(CodedUIUtils.browser, "PassagewaysLogin");
        CodedUIUtils.LoginGuest(CodedUIUtils.browser);
        CodedUIUtils.ClickLogon(CodedUIUtils.browser, "Logon");

        HtmlDiv overlay = CodedUIUtils.GetOverlay(CodedUIUtils.browser, "loadingOverlay");
        overlay.WaitForControlNotExist();

        CodedUIUtils.ClickLink(CodedUIUtils.browser, "Log Out");
        Playback.Wait(2000);
    }
```

Login Utils

```
   public static class CodedUIUtils
   {
    public static BrowserWindow browser;

    public static void LoginGuest(BrowserWindow browser)
    {
        EnterText(browser, "Email", "onboardTestUserId+guest@gmail.com");
        EnterText(browser, "LoginPassword", "Testing2!");
    }

    public static void ClickButton(UITestControl parent, string id)
    {
        var button = new HtmlButton(parent);
        button.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Id, id);

        Mouse.Click(button);
    }

    public static void EnterText(UITestControl parent, string id, string value)
    {
        var edit = new HtmlEdit(parent);
        edit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, id);
        edit.Text = value;
    }

    public static void ClickLink(UITestControl parent, string innerText)
    {
        var link = new HtmlHyperlink(parent);
        link.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.InnerText, innerText);
        link.WaitForControlReady();

        Mouse.Click(link);
    }

    public static void ClickLogon(UITestControl parent, string value)
    {
        var logonInput = new HtmlInputButton(parent);
        logonInput.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlInputButton.PropertyNames.ValueAttribute, value);

        Mouse.Click(logonInput);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a common best practice that when something may have loading time/intro animation or just in general to code with WaitForControlReady or WaitForControlExist Functions.

So unless you specifically really care about the loading overlay, then you can just put the function on the first object that the overlay is affecting you really want to interact with.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void StackOverflow()
        {
        BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("https://onboard.passageways.com/"));

        var _hyper = new HtmlButton(browser);
        _hyper.SearchProperties.Add("ID", "PassagewaysLogin");
        _hyper.WaitForControlReady();
        LoadingOverlay(browser);
        Mouse.Click(_hyper);

        var _email = new HtmlEdit(browser);

        _email.SearchProperties.Add("ID", "Email");
        _email.WaitForControlReady();
        LoadingOverlay(browser);
        Keyboard.SendKeys(_email, "testemail@email.com");
        Playback.Wait(10000);
        }

        public static void LoadingOverlay(BrowserWindow browser)
        {
        var _image = new HtmlDiv(browser);
        _image.SearchProperties.Add("ID", "loadingOverlay");
            _image.WaitForControlReady();
        }
```

Comment: What control am I waiting to be ready here? Is the LoadingOverlay a control that can be ready when it is done fading out?

Comment: I am assuming that you want to click on a control (a type of element) inside the div? A hyperlink or something?

Comment: Nope. The loadingOverlay covers the whole page. I need the loadingOverlay to complete its java script and fade out. When it fades out I need to hit a control on the webpage like login.

Comment: I added the method that worked on my machine for me on that site.

Comment: You could use the `WaitForControlCondition` on the loading overlay and check the Display property (or search the style attribute by force). You could also use for `WaitForControlNotExist`, which will wait until the control is hidden. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131072.aspx

Comment: @AlexCharizamhard I updated what code I am using. Your trick works on the first page only because I think the page renders so fast. It does not work on the actual login. Firefox still try's and clicks logout before it is ready.

Comment: Hmm... Depending on how much automation you want to do on that site it is always plausible, but not optimal, to just add an implicit Playback.Wait(2000).

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is depending on how big the org is depends on how long the wait time. So some times it might pass Playback.Wait(2000) and other times it will need Playback.Wait(10000) but what a waste to have it sit there if it doesn't need to sit there.

Comment: @AlexCharizamhard: Still no go on Firefox or Chrome. Firefox try's and clicks the logout button behind the loading screen and Chrome throws an error: Element is not clickable at point (353, 523). Other element would receive the click